# Is this the proper way to create a recipe page

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Hi I have created a website that need to be able to filter between recipes.

Currently displayed everything I create in content. It is intended that the dishes should be first, and not the recipes.

How is it possible? it is a better system to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views have a "Sort Criteria".

You can sort by "Content Type" in there,  assuming you're only showing 2 content types you should be able to set Ascending or Descending order to get them displaying the way you want.